# Avoid generating header comments with Hibernate generation tools

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

When generating DTO objects, hibernate tools generate comments in the header:

```
// Generated 22 avr. 2013 20:29:27 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1
```

Every generation the comments change (as they contains the generation date/time).

The problem is that in my SVN I end up having many non-usefull changes, so I have to check every single generated file to see whether to commit (if it contains actuals changes) or override it (if it's only the header).

Is there a way to avoid generating said header ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to customize the Freemarker template which is found in `hibernate-tools.jar`. Navigate to the `/pojo/Pojo.ftl` and remove the line `// Generated ${date} by Hibernate Tools ${version}`.

Checking this out might help: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=989777&view=next

An example of a Hibernate tool Ant task (by specifying `templatepath` and `hbmtemplate` attributes:

```
<hibernatetool destdir="hibernate-model-gen/pojo" templatepath="hibernate-model-gen/customized-templates">
    <jdbcconfiguration configurationfile="hibernate-model-gen/hibernate.cfg.xml" packagename="open.pub.proto.core.model" revengfile="hibernate-model-gen\gen-conf\hibernate.reveng.xml" detectmanytomany="true" />
    <hbmtemplate templateprefix="pojo/" template="pojo/Pojo.ftl" filepattern="{package-name}/{class-name}.java">
        <property key="jdk5" value="true" />
        <property key="ejb3" value="true" />
    </hbmtemplate>
</hibernatetool>
```

Comment: you mean i'll need to recompile hibernate plugin ? there's no way i can set a parameter instead ?

Comment: I located the Pojo.ftl file, I'm going to set the template directory property in the `Hibernate Code Generation Configurations` editor to my template directory and will let you know. Thanks.